Missed blocks when sending transactions - how to mitigate?
I've got a script running that sends a transactions to the chain every block. I've confirmed my network that tx are consistently being sent every 350ms and the RPC is receiving them with 10ms response time. It's running on an EC2 so I believe the network is not an issue.
When I'm reviewing the transactions on solscan, I'm noticing many gaps of 5-10 blocks where my transactions don't hit, and the occasional bunch up of three to five transactions in a single block.
Can someone help me understand the mechanics of how transactions are selected and included within blocks to explain why this might be happening, or if potentially there is another explanation? I'd like to see consistent block to block transactions if possible.
Or are there any better ways to troubleshoot & things I should be looking at?
